# What does p***take stand for?

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang

I have seen this word used in the media, I think it's a (British?) profane word and that is why it has asterisks in it. What is the full word spelled out though? Here is an example where it is used:

> One furious Brit said: 'It's an utter p***take that we're being left here like this.'

[Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-7933471/China-BLOCKING-Foreign-Office-airlifting-Britons-coronavirus-hit-Wuhan.html)

Comment: Along the lines of @tchrist I have heard “Take the p***” in British context. It would be a rearranging of your word. I could see this being the noun form as it were. It means to mock or ridicule something or someone. ETA: Read the article. Just use your imagination on what it means. He’s saying the government is taking a p*** on its trapped citizens. Figuratively speaking of course.

Comment: @Damila not "taking a piss on" but "taking the piss out of", i.e. insulting

Comment: @ChrisH I don't think "insulting" is quite spot-on.  I'd go for "deriding" or "mocking"

Comment: @PhilMJonesthat wroks.  Either is much closer than even figurative urination

Comment: I think censoring a word in a discussion about language and its usage is not very helpful nor is it common in a British context. So, why use asterisks at all? Nobody reading the word *pi\*\*take* will get less offended than reading *pisstake*.

Comment: @ian That's how OP has encountered the word. The question asks what is being censored.

Comment: The media will asterisk anything that's the slightest bit likely to offend their most traditional and elderly readers. I presume it stymies them from complaining  because they think they shouldn't know what the asterisks stand for.  Dictionaries ought to have entries for p*** a*** w*** etc. for the benefit of non-English people. But does '*' come before 'a' or after 'z'?

Comment: @Tashus Oh, right. Totally missed that. I'll let the comment (and my embarrassment) stand. :)

Comment: @nigel222 taken to extremes by the Sun, printing "t*ts" in text despite being willing to show pictures of bare breasts

Comment: Udder tw*ts.....

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary has this definition:

> **piss-take**  n. *colloquial* (chiefly *British, Australian*, and *New Zealand*) a parody, a send-up; an instance of mockery

Related to this is the earlier attested expression *take the piss (out of)*:

> *colloquial* (chiefly *British, Australian*, and *New Zealand*): to make fun (of), to mock, deride, satirize

(Ibid.)

Comment: How unusual is this? I can't recall ever seeing this before

Comment: I'm Irish and it is quite common. Even more so in the UK. Also take the piss can also mean to push your luck.

Comment: @JollyJoker If you're British I'm really surprised that you've never heard it. You must have led a very sheltered life:-) Don't worry, I'm extracting the urine!

Comment: @BoldBen JollyJoker was referring to seeing it writte, not hearing it. I can't remember seeing it written like this before, although I probably have.

Comment: A common, less crude variant is "taking the mick"

Comment: @BoldBen I'm not a native, so the English I see is mostly American or, if UK English, BBC news or stuff said in Parliament. But "take the piss" does sound vaguely familiar.

Answer (score -2):

## The word with asterisks is a word for urination that rhymes with "miss".

As for the meaning of the word when made into a compound word with "take", according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piss-take#English), it means "a parody" or "an unpleasant situation that is comparable to a parody".

Comment: I don't think you need to skate so widely around the word. This site has [no issues](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=cunt) with mentioning profane words in the context of a serious linguistic discussion.